# Assigning shared_ptr to weak_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I want to assign constructed shared_ptr to weak_ptr:

```
std::weak_ptr<void> rw  = std::shared_ptr<void>(operator new(60), [](void *pi) { operator delete(pi); });
```

But, when I do `rw.expired()`, it shows expired means it is empty. Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you hoping to use the `std::weak_ptr` for? What are you expecting it to do? Why do you want a `std::weak_ptr` rather than a `std::shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of `std::shared_ptr` is to release managed object when last shared pointer which points to it is destroyed or reassigned to somewhere else. You created a temporary shared ptr, assgned it to `std::weak_ptr` and then it is just destroyed at the end of the expression. You need to keep it alive:

```
auto shared = std::shared_ptr<void>(operator new(60), [](void *pi) { operator delete(pi); });
std::weak_ptr<void> rw  = shared;
```

now `rw` would not expire at least while `shared` is still alive.

Comment: Thanks Slava. What is the way to keep it alive?

Comment: here shared will be local variable and it will be lost once out of scope. I want to access it in some other function. So can I make it class member variable?

Comment: Yes you can copy this pointer to a member variable or two, you can return it from a function and so on - so if you keep at least one pointer to refer to this data it will be alive and so this weak_ptr will show that.

Comment: But I cannot make "auto shared" member variable as we have to make it const and initialise it. Is there any other way?

Comment: "But I cannot make "auto shared" member variable as we have to make it const and initialise it." `auto` is used in this code to show you the idea you would not use `auto` as a member variable, looks like you need to learn the language to higher level, SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: "So I thought using weak_ptr would avoid any memory leaks." looks like you do not understand what you are doing, I do not know what is your VIRT but you allocate memory and memory leak is when you do not properly deallocate it, it is irrelevant to this example

Comment: I am sorry for my vague and unclear comment!! My simple objective is to know if `std::shared_ptr<void> rw = std::shared_ptr<void>(operator new(60), [](void *pi) { operator delete(pi); });` can cause memory leak or not?